# Unable to load data into Htable using Mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am very new to Hbase and Hadoop. I am getting confused with MapReduce concept, I want to know the flow of execution in Mapreduce F/w. I tried searching google for a way to read data from a file and load the data into Htable using the `Put` class using reducer. I have a file in HDFS which I need to read from Hbase Mapreducer and load the data into Htable.

Can any one show me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Mapper with out reducer. As reducer can be used for sorting and you just need the file data to be stored in Hbase directly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the reduce step.  In your map class, when you get a record, directly insert it into HBase.  There is no need to shuffle / sort your puts before sending them to HBase.  This means that all you have to do is create an instance variable for your HTable and initialize it in the setup method; then in your map method, create a put for your record, and add it to your HTable.  Finally, in your cleanup method, make sure you flush your HTable.